# MySQL: Combining the results of 2 columns in one statement

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

Lets just say I have 2 result sets as follows

```
 R1        R2
| 1 |     | 5 |
| 2 |     | 6 |
| 3 |     | 7 |
| 4 |     | 8 |
```

I need to combine these result into a single SET,
So I'd have something like this:

```
 R3
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
```

Currently,
I'm doing this with a a UNION like so:

```
SELECT c_1 AS result FROM table WHERE c_1=3 OR c_2=3
UNION
SELECT c_2 AS result FROM table WHERE c_1=3 OR c_2=3
```

Basically, I end up performing the same operation twice on the table,
Just retrieving different rows each time.
Is there a more efficient way I could go about doing this?
I need the result in a single column since that's a limitation of IN.
In the long run, what I need to do is this

```
SELECT name FROM person WHERE person_id IN
(SELECT c_1 AS result FROM table WHERE c_1=3 OR c_2=3
UNION
SELECT c_2 AS result FROM table WHERE c_1=3 OR c_2=3)
```

Is there a better way to go about finding all of this?
Any and all help is welcome.

Comment: SQL declares the wanted result, not the calculation method. For that use the command `EXPLAIN`

Comment: Can you not use `SELECT c_1 as r1, c_2 as r2...`?  Also, are you using the `result` variable?

Comment: Personally I avoid using IN whenever possible, unless I know it will always be a small set in a small table. Michael Berkowski's answer is my preferred way using `inner join`. Just make sure you have indexes on everything you intend to use as keys or set up proper foreign keys for performance.

Comment: @Levi Aye, will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of the `IN ()` subquery, you can perform an `INNER JOIN` on *either* `c_1 OR c_2`

```
SELECT
  name
FROM 
  person
  /* Join against the other table on *either* column c_1 or c_2 */
  INNER JOIN `table` ON `table`.c_1 = person.person_id OR `table`.c_2 = person.person_id
WHERE
  /* And the WHERE condition only needs to be applied once */
  c_1 = 3 OR c_2 = 3
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d159/1

Comment: Good stuff! Works like a charm.